# How to loop through and assert JSON array objects in JMeter if they have the same name?

Tags: json, jmeter, assertion

I have the below JSON response to be validated. I need to validate all the **"createdDate"** from all the Arrays irrespective. Is there any easy way to capture them or loop through them (since it has the same object name, but in different arrays) and put them in variables to do an assertion against their corresponding values from a JDBC response?

Right now I have used JSON Assertion for each and every "createdDate" using the JSON path to validate against the database value.

```
{
    "someobject1": 123,
    "Array1": 
    [
        {
            "someobject2": 2,
            "createdDate": "2019-03-26T20:29:44.631+0000",
            "someobject3": "SCRIPT1"
        },

        {
            "someobject4": 3,
            "createdDate": "2019-03-27T20:29:44.631+0000",
            "someobject5": "SCRIPT2"
        }
    ],

    "Array2": 
    [
        {
            "someobject6": 4,
            "createdDate": "2019-03-28T20:29:44.631+0000",
            "someobject7": "SCRIPT3"
        },

        {
            "someobject8": 5,
            "createdDate": "2019-03-29T20:29:44.631+0000",
            "someobject9": "SCRIPT4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) configured like:

- Assert JSON Path Exists: `$..createdDate`
- Expected Value: `["2019-03-26T20:29:44.631+0000","2019-03-27T20:29:44.631+0000","2019-03-28T20:29:44.631+0000","2019-03-29T20:29:44.631+0000"]`

Full configuration:

[image]

More information:

- [JSON Path: Deep Scan Operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [JSON Path Examples](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Is it possible to compare it one to one. In case if one of them fails, can any of the listeners tell?